# how to order query From firestore based on timestamp in ionic 4

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I've performed a query to Firebase firestore and the data is being called perfectly. but I can't use any kind of ordering on this query.

here is my code:

```js
   this.dressCollection = db.collection<Dress>('dress').orderBy("date", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
    this.dress = this.dressCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
      })
    );
```

I get this 2 errors:

`Property 'orderBy' does not exist on type 'AngularFirestoreCollection<Dress>'`

and

`Cannot find name 'Query'`

Comment: did you add timestep into your collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
, 'date',ref=>ref.orderBy('date','asc')
```

inside the collection